# Ruby undefined constant NameError

Tags: ruby, class, require

I have the following code: http://scrp.at/FB

```
# Error:
# bin/rpg:5:in `<main>': uninitialized constant RubyPasswordGenerator::Korben (NameError)
```

In file "bin/rpg"

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require_relative "../lib/ruby_password_generator"

puts RubyPasswordGenerator::Korben.new
```

In "lib/ruby_password_generator.rb"

```
require_relative "ruby_password_generator/ruby_password_generator"
require_relative "ruby_password_generator/password_generator"
require_relative "ruby_password_generator/version"

# DEBUG
require "pp"

module RubyPasswordGenerator
end

require_relative "ruby_password_generator/algo/korben"
```

In "algo/korben.rb"

```
module RubyPasswordGenrator

  class Korben

    M_LOWERCAS_LETTERS    = ("a".."z").to_a
    M_UPPERCASE_LETTERS   = ("A".."Z").to_a
    M_NUMBERS             = (0..9).to_a
    M_SPECCIAL_CHARACTERS = "!@#()_-+=[]{}".split("")

    def initialize(length = 42)
      raise ArgumentError unless length.is_a?(Integer)
      raise ArgumentError unless length >= 3 && length <= 255

      @length = length
    end

    def generate
      password = ""
      (0...@length).each do
        char = (M_LOWERCAS_LETTERS + M_UPPERCASE_LETTERS + M_NUMBERS + M_SPECCIAL_CHARACTERS).shuffle.sample
        password << char
      end

      password
    end

  end
end
```

The file structure looks like:

```
# .
# ├── Gemfile
# ├── Gemfile.lock
# ├── LICENSE.markdown
# ├── NERD_tree_3
# ├── README.markdown
# ├── Rakefile
# ├── bin
# │   └── rpg
# ├── lib
# │   ├── ruby_password_generator
# │   │   ├── algo
# │   │   │   ├── korben.rb
# │   │   │   └── marvin.rb
# │   │   ├── helpers
# │   │   ├── password_generator.rb
# │   │   ├── ruby_password_generator.rb
# │   │   └── version.rb
# │   └── ruby_password_generator.rb
# ├── ruby_password_generator.gemspec
# └── spec
#     ├── algo
#     │   ├── korben_spec.rb
#     │   └── marvin_spec.rb
#     ├── password_generator_spec.rb
#     ├── ruby_password_generator_spec.rb
#     └── spec_helper.rb
#
# 7 directories, 19 files
```

I really don't know why I am getting an `uninitialized constant` "NameError" error. I included the file properly using `require_relative`. I also tried autoload and require, but that didn't solve anything. I am using ruby 1.9.2-p180.
If anybody knows what's going on please explain me.

Comment: I reformatted the file layout in your sample to make it more readable. If it's not correct edit your question and roll it back to remove the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module RubyPasswordGenrator
  class Korben
```

You're missing an e in the module name. Thus the Korben class exists in the `RubyPasswordGenrator` module not the `RubyPasswordGenerator` module and `RubyPasswordGenerator::Korben` does indeed not exist.

Comment: I'm such an idiot. I've been stuck on this for a long time. I need to learn to type. Thanks a lot and sorry for my idiocy.

Comment: @Aziz Light, add `-wW2` to your `#!` line, or when you invoke Ruby, to turn on more verbose warnings. Ruby would probably have told you about it.

Comment: @the Tin Man: I don't think warnings would detect one constant name being very similar to another. It's not like warning about non-existent instance variables. Also, are you sure it's `-wW2`?

Comment: A misspelled method or class in a reference should generate a warning when you turn on the verbose warning level. `-w` means turn on warnings, `-W2` means set warnings to the maximum level. `2` is the default but I use it so it's explicit. Doing this should return more usable info when debugging a problem. It's not going to hurt, and will help catch misspelled variables while developing.

Comment: @theTinMan: Misspelling class or module names causes "undefined constant" errors, not warnings.